# How to compute $\sum_{n,m=2}^{\infty}{n^{-m}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> How to compute $\sum_{n,m=2}^{\infty}{n^{-m}}$

Here's my progress:

I suppose $\sum_{n,m=2}^{\infty}{n^{-m}}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^m}}$, so we're looking at a convergent qeometric series since $0<\frac{1}{n}:=q\leq 1$. I shifted the index:$$\sum_{n,m=2}^{\infty}{n^{-m}}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{1}{n+2}\right)^m}}$$ So now we have $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n+2}}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{n+2}{n+1}}$$ Since $\frac{n+2}{n+1} \to 1 \neq 0$, we can conclude that the series diverges. Is that correct?

Comment: When you shifted the index, you got it backwards.  $m$ stills runs from $2$ and $n$ from $0$.

Comment: It's not $1/(n+2)^m$, it's $1/n^{m+2}$ (with the inner sum over $m$ starting at $0$ and the outer sum over $n$ starting at $2$).

Comment: Yeah, I messed up the index shift, its all clear now, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, for every $n>1$,
$$\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}n^{-m}=\frac{1}{n(n-1)},$$
and 
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n-1)}=1$$

Comment: Well, i messed with the index shift since I shifted $n$ instead of $m$! Merci beaucoup.